# Confusion in understanding the Lambertian law

Tags: optics, photonics

Lambertian law states that the luminous intensity of light emitted from a perfectly diffusing surface is proportional to the $cos(\theta)$ between the surface normal and the direction of observation. I understand it in the following way. If we will observe some surface scattering light equally, for us the light power per unit area should be the same for all angles of observations. Since the observation area decreases with the angle the scattered light power should be also decreased.

However, if I think about it in terms of a number of photons I am confused. I can imagine a perfectly diffusing surface as a surface with a lot of very small light sources, each producing a certain constant number of photons per solid angle in all directions. It means that if I place some photodetector at different observation angles I should always measure the same number of photons because it should equal $N_{sources}*n$, where $N_{sources}$ is a number of light sources within the surface and $n$ is a number of photons emitted in a certain observation angle. However, according to the Lambertian law, I should observe the drop in the number of photons increasing the observation angle. Please, help me with the confusion. Probably, my problem is terminology. Being a laser physicist I don't get used to such definition as luminous intensity, because for me intensity is energy divided by the illumination area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each producing a certain constant number of photons per solid angle in all directions.

This would be non-Lambertian emission.

In Lambertian scattering/reflection *most* rays *are* emitted along the normal and *fewer* as we approach large angles.

Comment: Basically, your answer could end at "This would be non-Lambertian emission. In Lambertian scattering/reflection most rays are emitted along the normal and fewer as we approach large angles.":) What you write further was mentioned in the question as my understanding of the Lambertian law. So, then a perfectly diffusing surface can't be viewed as a superposition of point sources, each producing equal scatterings in all angles. I would say that it is not clear intuitively and this is why I have this question :)

Comment: @AntonBaranikov updated answer to simplify it